# Launch screen custom image for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiimageview

I need to present different image on the launch screen for iPad.
Our designer provided only 2 images:

- one for iPhone portrait
- one for iPad landscape

So I cannot use Launch images and assets catalog

Instead of that I'm trying to use LaunchScreen.xib,
I'm trying to name them like it is described here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html

with ~ipad and ~iphone postfixes

But I didn't manage to figure out how I should place them in the assets catalog

[image]

[image]

How can I present different images for iPad and iPhone

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

I found out that it could be done with right click on the detail asset view in xCode

Answer (score 0):

Try to open assets catalog in xcode and choose LaunchImage.
Next right click and select New Launch Image.

After that you will have new asset. [image here.](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/07/14/55a4d79a42a6e.png)
Put you images there.

Next step is delete old LaunchImage asset and rename new.